# What are these violet shrubs with pink flowers?

Tags: shrubs, flowering

The shrubs are very short. The pink flowers are small but beautiful. I have seen this in a warm climate. What is the name of this plant?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's [Tradescantia pallida](https://worldofsucculents.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Tradescantia-pallida-Wandering-Jew4.jpg). Although there are many hybrids of this plant, I believe that you've pictured the species because the leaves are less pointed and less purple than most of the common hybrids. Technically, it's a perennial, not a shrub (it doesn't have woody stems, for instance). The plant can root at each leaf node (the area of the stem with the white sheath on it, most visible in the lower right corner of the photo) so it's easy to get cutting from it. In non-tropical climates, it's used as either an annual groundcover or as a houseplant.

More information is [here](https://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/plantfinder/plantfinderdetails.aspx?kempercode=c137).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!